# No state in response after callback in oidc-client-js

Tags: angular, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I think this is an error related to angular 5.2.8  & 6 .
With angular 5.2.7 work fine. 
I create a [ng5 branch](https://github.com/client-sdk-samples/sample-angular-OidcClient/tree/ng5) and update angular to latest 5.2.8 and the error com in!
anybody can direct me to an angular 5.2.8 and later sample with oidc-client-js ?

Comment: Maybe show some code or give some more context

Comment: @David   See the https://github.com/client-sdk-samples/sample-angular-OidcClient/tree/ng5

Comment: I wonder if these are similar - https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/195

Comment: Did you managed to figure this out? Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @21seconds  my answer work fine to me , please mark it as accept if it work for you too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is caused by URI encoding of state in the window.location.hash.
For me this fix the issue:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
window.location.hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
// authorizedCallback returns wrong result when hash is URI encoded
this.oidcSecurityService.authorizedCallback();
} else {
this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `window.location.hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);` This is the line I needed.

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing something custom like me and your issue has nothing to do with hash location, just ignore it:

```
  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    }).catch((err) => {});
  }
```

Comment: +1 for this, this is exactly what I initially did and this confirms it. I am using React with React-Router and for some reason the state is not read by the oidc-client.